# more than one row returned by a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-insert

I am writing a query to insert values in a table.
It is giving me an error.

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO res_partner(
                        name,
                        company_id,
                        create_date,
                        street,
                        city,
                        display_name,
                        zip,
                        supplier,
                        ref,
                        is_company,
                        customer,
                        street2,
                        employee,
                        write_date,
                        active,
                        write_uid,
                        lang,
                        create_uid,
                        notify_email) 
       VALUES(
              (SELECT shipping_address_name FROM temp_unicom),
              1,
              LOCALTIMESTAMP,
              (SELECT shipping_address_line_1 FROM temp_unicom;),
              (SELECT shipping_address_city FROM temp_unicom),
              (SELECT shipping_address_name FROM  temp_unicom),
              (SELECT shipping_address_pincode FROM temp_unicom),
              FALSE,
              (Select sale_order_item_code FROM temp_unicom),
              FALSE,
              TRUE,
              (SELECT shipping_address_line_2 FROM temp_unicom),
              FALSE,
              LOCALTIMESTAMP,
              TRUE,
              1,
              'en_US',
              1,
              'always');
```

Error:

`ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

********** Error **********

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

I know that each select subquery returns multiple rows, but I don't know how to fix the error.
I have approximately 15,000 rows in my `temp_unicom` table and I am trying to insert data from `temp_unicom` to `res_partner`.

Comment: You need some where clause in your sub queries so they return a single value.  You can't insert multiple values in an `insert into`.

Comment: Problem is i dont have a where clause. I need to copy data from temp_unicom to res_partner.     LOCALTIMESTAMP give the current timestamp of my system.

Comment: `insert into res_partner (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) select cola,colb,1,'en_US',colc from  temp_unicom`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is not correct syntax for `insert ... select` statement. If you want to insert many rows from `temp_unicom` table you should rewrite your query as below

```
Insert into res_partner
(name,company_id,create_date,street,city,display_name,zip,supplier,ref,is_company,customer,street2,employee,write_date,active,write_uid,lang,create_uid,notify_email) 
Select shipping_address_name,1, LOCALTIMESTAMP, shipping_address_name, 
shipping_address_line_1,shipping_address_city,
shipping_address_name,shipping_address_pincode,sale_order_item_code,FALSE,
shipping_address_line_2,FALSE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, TRUE,1,'en_US',1,'always'
from temp_unicom
```